# Negative number modular positive number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to understand how `-1 % 5 = 4`.

I already know that `1 % 5 = 1` and `2 % 5 = 2` and so on. Please explain this when it is negative as in the previous example.

Comment: Uhm... What? It didn't evaluate it M10 or M9. Are you talking about `Mod`?

Comment: What do you mean in M10 and M9 ?

Comment: Mathematica 10 and Mathematica 9.

Comment: yes it is the MOD

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a different programming language than *Mathematica* or about mathematics.  If it about how *Mathematica* defines the function `Mod` (**not** MOD), then why write `%`?

Answer (score 2):

```
 -5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3    4    5
--+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---
  |                   |    |    |
-5|                   |-1 0|    |1
  |         =         |    | == |
            4                 1
```

The mod function defined as the amount by which number exceeds the largest integer multiple of the divisor that is not greater than that number. And an illustration of this definition.

So, [`Mod[1, 5] = 1`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html) and [`Mod[-1, 5] = 4`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are asking why $-1 \equiv 4 \bmod 5$.

Let $m$ be a positive integer. For any integer $a$, there is a unique integer $b  \in \{0, \dots, m - 1\}$ such that $a - b$ is a multiple of $m$ and we write $a \equiv b \bmod m$, or in the notation you are using, $a\% m = b$.

In this particular example, $-1 - 4 = - 5$ which is a multiple of $5$; here $a = -1$, $b = 4$ and $m = 5$. So $-1 \equiv 4 \bmod 5$, or $-1\%5 = 4$.

In general, when you are trying determine a negative number modulo a positive number, you can just keep adding the modulus until you get a non-negative number.

**Example:** To determine $-36 \bmod 7$, we do the following computations

\begin{align*}
-36 + 7 &= -29\\
-29 + 7 &= -22\\
-22 + 7 &= -15\\
-15 + 7 &= -8\\
-8 + 7 &= -1\\
-1 + 7 &= 6\ \checkmark
\end{align*}

So $-36 \equiv 6 \bmod 7$.